# Trouble when declaring x = somelist.append, and using x to append some value to somelist

Tags: python-3.x, append

In the following code, in the first `if T < 2.3` there is a line that is using the variable `self_magnetization_evolution_append` that is declared before the loop starts. This is correctly appending the output from the method `self.calc_magnetization()` to the  `self.magnetization_evolution` list. However, when I reference the same variable inside the `else` block, it does not append anything. I checked that `self.calc_magnetization()` is producing output, and the program actually goes inside the loop  `for mcstep in range(mc_post_eqsteps)`. Any idea what is going on?

```
Tlist = np.arange(Ti, Tf, step)

        self_magnetization_evolution_append = self.magnetization_evolution.append
        self_magnetization_append = self.magnetization.append
        for T in Tlist:

            if T < 2.3:

                for gilstep in range(gil_eq_steps):
                    self.continuous_time_step(T, 0, False)
                for gilstep in range(gil_post_eqsteps):
                    self.continuous_time_step(T, 0, False)
                    self_magnetization_evolution_append(self.calc_magnetization())

            else:
                for mcstep in range(int(mc_eq_steps)):
                    self.metropolis_step(T)
                for mcstep in range(mc_post_eqsteps):
                    self.metropolis_step(T)
                    self_magnetization_evolution_append(self.calc_magnetization())
```

Comment: Is ``mc_post_eqsteps`` 0? Note that with the code shown, we have to guess significant parts of the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, it is not 0, it goes inside that loop and i checked that inside that loop `self.calc_magnetization()` is producing output. I edited the post to clearify that, thank you.

Comment: When you say "it does not append anything", what does it do instead? Do you ever reset or replace ``self.magnetization_evolution``, e.g. in ``self.calc_magnetization``?